# Angular Material Table - how do I hide the table rows until searched?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm still pretty new to Angular and I thought this was straightforward, but I can't seem to get my app to work properly to the way I want. So I have a search bar and a datatable using Angular Material. I want to be able to NOT show the items in the table until you enter something in the search. But all the while I want to keep the header of the table that shows each column name.

So I have my project here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-jgqyne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

When first loaded in, I want the table to not show any results (periodic element) and just show the header. There is a gray area that is supposed to be for instructions handled by `displayPrompt`. This is supposed to be there only when the user has not searched anything or search is empty. Once user searches something, the instruction area will be hidden and you will either get results from the table or nothing. Once the user deletes the word from search, instructions should be shown again and the table results should be hidden again.

I am able to get the first parts to work, but can't seem to get the results to be hidden again after the search is cleared. The results are inside a `div` which has an `ngIf` using `displayResults` that should be updated accordingly inside the `applyFilter()`. It is showing the `displayResults` being updated when the search is cleared though so I am not sure why that div is not hidden.

html:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<div *ngIf="displayResults">
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.search = filterValue;
    if(this.search.length === 0) {
      this.displayResults = false;
      this.displayPrompt = true;
    }
    else {
      this.dataSource.filter = this.search.trim().toLowerCase();
      this.displayResults = true;
      this.displayPrompt = false;
    }
 }
```

Maybe I am missing something basic, but I have not been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the condition for showing the rows (remove it):

```
<div *ngIf="displayResults">
```

Instead, in your class, initialize the data source like this:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

Then in `applyFilter` method:

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.search = filterValue;
    console.log(this.search.length);
    if(this.search.length === 0) {
      this.dataSource.data = [];
      this.displayResults = false;
      this.displayPrompt = true;
    }
    else {
      this.dataSource.data = MockData;
      this.dataSource.filter = this.search.trim().toLowerCase();
      this.displayResults = true;
      this.displayPrompt = false;
    }
  }
```

The idea is to fill the data source with the mock data only if the user types in a search term.

Comment: Thank you! I think that is one idea I had thought of but I wasn't sure if I should be constantly setting/resetting the dataSource to the MockData.

Comment: Another idea: set `this.dataSource.filter = '*'` when the search term is empty. This filter yields no results. No need to reassign `this.dataSource.data`

Comment: What if there are actual results that contain '*'? Wouldn't this not be ideal in that case?

Comment: Simply compare with a string that will never be likely to match an item. such as '#$%&*'